# how to extract text within font tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am making my first program with beautifulsoup and my html file has code snippet like this

```
......
......
......

<font face="verdana" size="3">5 n i D 1 C</font>
......
......
```

I want to extract `5 n i D 1 C` from within the `<font>` tag. I am doing

`ele=soup('font', face="verdana",size="3")`  then

```
ele.Contents()
```

but i am getting an error `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'font'`
when i do

```
 print ele
```

output is

```
[<font face="verdana" size="3">5 n i D 1 C</font>]
```

that means it is searching correctly, please help me how to extract the given text.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ele[0].contents[0]
u'5 n i D 1 C'
```

Comment: 1. `ele=soup('font', face="verdana",size="3")`, here ele's type is a ResultSet, which seems like a list. So to get the first font element you have to get the first item in ResultSet, i.e. `ele[0]`. 2. ele[0].contents is a list of strings. So to get the first string you again access the 0-th item.

Comment: also, how to store just `5niD1C` in a variable?

Comment: `my_var = ele[0].contents[0]`

Comment: but this also stores newlines and tabs with my_var, how to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
ele[0].Contents()
```

instead of

```
ele.Contents()
```

ele is a ResultSet and not the first result, might want to check the documentation for something that only returns the first result. I'm not familiar with BeautifulSoup